# BigQuery - Nested Case Statement and Multi Criteria Case Statement - Wrong Results

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to understand how the CASE statement processes in BigQuery. I built a CASE statement, added 2 WHEN/THEN clauses and the results were correct. I added 2 more WHEN/THEN and the results were way outside of the criteria. The goal of this CASE Statement is to **1.** Compare the date of the data against x date **2.** Compare the project value to the criteria in WHEN/THEN. I need to nest a CASE Statement in the "Else" clause so I can check for the next date as the values will differ during various date ranges.

Here is a sample of my Case Statement. For any data having a date less than 4/30/2022, it will compare the customstringfield2 value to the criteria in the WHEN. If it matches, return the THEN. When I execute it with only the "Capital" and "Oper" clauses (the first two WHEN/THEN), the results are correct. As soon as I run it with the "PTO" and "Admin" clauses (the last two WHEN/THEN) - it starts classifying items completely backwards. For example, for a value starting with "016" - it shows as "PTO". There is nothing in the WHEN criteria for "PTO" that even has the term "016". Quite confused what is happening. Any education is greatly appreciated.

```
CASE DATE < '2022-04-30' 
WHEN project LIKE 'USA%' OR project LIKE '016%' OR project LIKE '014%'
THEN "Capital"

WHEN project NOT LIKE 'USA%' AND project NOT LIKE '016%' OR project NOT LIKE '014%' OR project NOT LIKE 'Admin' OR project NOT LIKE 'PTO' OR project NOT LIKE 'Time Out' OR project NOT LIKE 'Personal'
THEN "Oper"

WHEN project = 'PTO' OR project = 'Time Out' OR project = 'Personal'
THEN "PTO"

WHEN project = 'Admin'
THEN "Admin"

ELSE (CASE DATE BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2023-05-10'
      WHEN activity like 'Capital%' and (project LIKE 'USA%' OR project LIKE  '016%' OR project LIKE '014%') 
      THEN "Capital"
      ELSE "Oper" END)
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your case like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN DATE < '2022-04-30' 
  THEN
    CASE
      WHEN project LIKE 'USA%' OR project LIKE '016%' OR project LIKE '014%'
      THEN "Capital"

      WHEN project NOT LIKE 'USA%' AND project NOT LIKE '016%' OR project NOT LIKE '014%' OR project NOT LIKE 'Admin' OR project NOT LIKE 'PTO' OR project NOT LIKE 'Time Out' OR project NOT LIKE 'Personal'
      THEN "Oper"

      WHEN project = 'PTO' OR project = 'Time Out' OR project = 'Personal'
      THEN "PTO"

      WHEN project = 'Admin'
      THEN "Admin"
    END

  WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2023-05-10'
  THEN
    CASE
      WHEN activity like 'Capital%' and (project LIKE 'USA%' OR project LIKE  '016%' OR project LIKE '014%') 
      THEN "Capital"
      
      ELSE "Oper"
    END
END
```

In your initial case statement, you have `CASE DATE < '2022-04-30'` which will be either True or False, which will give you unpredictable results in your subsequent `WHEN`/`THEN` statements.